# Принцип инверсии зависимостей

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

В книге "Внедрение зависимостей на платформе .NET" написано, что принцип инверсии зависимостей диктует обязательное распространение абстракций с их собственными модулями.

Полный отрывок:

> Если принцип инверсии зависимостей диктует обязательное распространение абстракций
> с их собственными модулями, не нарушает ли интерфейс доменного уровня IProductService этот
> принцип? К тому же IProductService потребляется уровнем пользовательского интерфейса, но реализован, как показано на рис. 3.12, доменным уровнем. Да, это нарушение принципа инверсии зависимостей.
> Если бы мы были заинтересованы в исправлении этого нарушения, то нужно было бы убрать IProductService из доменного уровня. Но перемещение IProductService на уровень пользователь ского интерфейса сделает наш доменный уровень зависимым от него. Поскольку доменный уровень
> является центральной частью приложения, нам не хотелось бы, чтобы он зависел от
> чего-либо еще. Кроме того, эта зависимость не позволила бы впоследствии заменить
> уровень пользовательского интерфейса.
> Все это означает, что для устранения нарушения в нашем решении нужны еще
> два дополнительных проекта: один для изолированного уровня пользовательского интерфейса без точки входа (Composition Root), а другой — для абстракции IProductService, которой владеет уровень пользовательского интерфейса. Но сугубо из прагматичных соображений для данного примера мы решили не следовать по этому маршруту, оставив нарушение в покое.
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В книге не написано конкретного решения этой проблемы, а лишь говорится каким способом ее можно решить, а именно:

1. Создать проект для изолированного уровня пользовательского интерфейса без точки входа (Composition Root)
2. Создать проект для абстракции IProductService, которой владеет уровень пользовательского интерфейса

Проблема в том, что я не очень понимаю как реализовать этот предложенный способ

Comment: Да, как-то сложно всё. По факту видимо достаточно вынести интерфейс в отдельный проект или хотя бы namespace. И тогда в UI достаточно будет подключения этой сущности, где лежит интерфейс. И в доменный уровень тоже. Таким образом и UI и домен не будут зависеть друг от друга, а только от этой абстракции - интерфейса. Ну а настроенный DI фреймворк будет внедрять в исполняемый код вместо интерфейса его реализацию.

Comment: @CrazyElf , спасибо за ответ. Честно говоря, даже после вашего ответа яснее не стало. Можете нарисовать блок-схему? А что если я, например, абстракцию репозитория буду использовать не только в доменном уровне, но и в сервисном уровне (или уровне приложения) для реализации транзакционного сценария или активной записи? Мне что, тоже создавать отдельный проект? Ведь, изначально, абстракция хранилась в доменном уровне, а по-итогу используется и в доменном и в сервисном уровне (хотя и решить это можно перенеся абстракции на уровень сервиса и взаимодействовать с бд только там, но все же)

Comment: Погодите, абстракция - это интерфейс, а не его реализация. Именно поэтому вы спокойно выносите абстракции-интерфейсы в отдельный уровень, который доступен из всех остальных уровней, где эти абстракции нужны. И спокойно их везде используете, благодаря DI фреймворку, который связывает абстракции с реализациями. А реализация интерфейса при этом остаётся там, где ей лучше всего быть. На доменном уровне - значит на доменном. В этом и прелесть IoC + DI.

Comment: @CrazyElf, Забудьте мой прошлый ответ, я зациклился на одном лишь определение, которое еще и не правильно понял. Вернемся к основной проблеме и к вашему первому комментарию. Я вспомнил про статью (https://habr.com/ru/articles/718916/), где абстракции выносятся в отдельный уровень (namespace или слой, не знаю как точно назвать) между сервисным (приложением) и инфраструктурным уровнем, а реализация находится на сервисном уровне. Хотя, все равно не могу понять, почему нельзя было и абстракцию и реализацию положить в сервисный уровень.

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что мы хотим добиться `loose coupling`. Если вы абстракцию положите в сервисный слой, то те слои, которые используют эту абстракцию, "привяжутся" к сервисному слою. А это плохо. Чем меньше слои знают друг о друге, тем лучше во всех смыслах. Поэтому лучше пускай все слои знают про легковесный слой абстракций-интерфейсов, чем о таких тяжеловесах, как сервисный слой. При слабой связности всё проще - и компиляция, и тестирование и много чего ещё.